# What kind of failover is used by jdbc oracle thin driver when multiple hosts provided

Tags: oracle, jdbc, failover, ojdbc

I am looking into a code that is using the Oracle jdbc thin driver to connect to Oracle 12c database.  I am new to jdbc / oracle driver.  The url used to create a connection to db:

```
dbUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin@(description=(load_balance=off)(failover=on)
              (address=(protocol=tcp)(host=host1.bar.com)(port=2000))
              (address=(protocol=tcp)(host=host2.bar.com)(port=2000)) 
              (connect_data=(service_name=PROD)(failover_mode=(type=select)(method=basic)(retries=5)(delay=5))))
```

by calling method:

```
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
```

I have a few questions:
- Is the driver using "Transparent Application Failover (TAF)" or "Fast Connection Failover (FCF)" mechanism?
- Can I register a callback to get notification when a failover has occurred?   If so, can someone please point me to a document or sample code.
- Is there an API in the connection object to find the current database connected to (that will return either host1 or host2 or none)?
- I am not able to find the documentation that describes the parameters in the above dbUrl string.  Can someone please point me to some links to documentation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: Update:
Information about the environment.  We are not using the Universal Connection Pool (UCP), using our won connection pool/manager.  Version info : JDBC8, Oracle DB 12c, JDK 8.

Answer (score 0):

(a) Whether FCF is enabled or not will depend on the the version of the JDBC driver that you are using. If you are using Universal Connection Pool (UCP) from 12.2 version then, FCF will be enabled by default. Refer to [UCP Developers guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjucp/fast-connection-failover.html#GUID-126F8C9B-C0B3-426B-B07D-4B127BBDD867) for more details about FCF.

**FAILOVER:**
It enables connect time failover.  When turned ON, it instructs Oracle Net to fail over to a different listener if the first listener fails. The number of addresses in the list determines how many addresses are tried. When set to OFF, it instructs Oracle Net to try only one address. Always set FAILVOER=ON for ADG or DG database configuration.

**LOAD_BALANCE:**
 This parameter enables connection time load balancing thus enabling listeners 
to make routing decisions based on the load on the nodes. When this parameter is set to OFF, Oracle Net tries the protocol addresses sequentially until one succeeds. When this parameter is set to ON for a SCAN based address, new connection requests will be randomly assigned to one of the 3 SCAN-based IP addresses resolved by DNS. This randomization enables all listeners to share the job of servicing incoming connect requests.  For clients without SCAN, Oracle Net services randomly 
selects an address in the address list and connects to the listener on that node

(b) You can find the host that you are connected to by using the below SQL.

SELECT host_name FROM v$instance;

Comment: Thank you for the info. I updated my question version info.  I want to know which host a connection is connection to programmatically from the application/client.  Should I used "OracleConnection".  Also, any idea how to register a callback to get notified of failover occurrence.

Comment: I feel you are mistaken. The way the connection is being created, by the DriverManager, the connection failover is handled by the client, at the client level, irrespective of the configuration of the Oracle database.  Your thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There is [simplefan.jar](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/downloads/jdbc-ucp-183-5013470.html) that you can leverage to handle the events related to Instance UP, DOWN etc.,

Make sure you have ons.jar, simplefan.jar along with JDBC driver in the classpath.

Comment: Can you please provide link to sample code that, that would be greatly helpful. I am not able to find sample codes online.